# React-Native = Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: react-native

I have this error, and i didn't have it before :
[here is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ozga.png)
Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

This error is located at:
in Connect (at LoginForm.js:75)

```
render() {
const { inputStyle, containerStylePass, containerStyleIdent, barStyle, textInputStyle } = styles;

return (
   <View>
    <View>{/* all the password form*/}
      <View style={containerStylePass}>
      icon
        <Text style={inputStyle}>Mot de passe</Text>
      </View>
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry
        autoCorrect={false}
        style={textInputStyle}
      />
      <View style={barStyle} />
    </View>

    <View>
      <Connect />
    </View>
  </View>
```

I don't know why is  an error, can anyone help?

here is my  code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';

class Connect extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setState({ butPressed: true })}>
        <LinearGradient
          colors={['#56EDFF', '#42F4A0']}
          start={{ x: 0.0, y: 1.0 }} end={{ x: 1.0, y: 1.0 }}
        >
          <Text style={textStyle}>
            Se connecter
          </Text>;
        </LinearGradient>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please include the text content of your error within your question.

Comment: Can you show your Connect component

Comment: I add the connect component @Deva

Comment: I include the text content of my error @Dragonthoughts

Comment: i think you can remove onPress={this.setState({ butPressed: true })} in connect component and run it

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ butPressed: true })}>
```

instead of

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.setState({ butPressed: true })}>
```

Assigning {this.setState} to onPress without arrow function cause to render over and over again because setState casing the component to render again and then it comes again to the assignment of onPress = {}.
Using arrow function instead causing to assign a function so the setState is actually doesn't happen until the function is activated. (only when onPress is activated)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had a red herring, it was complaining about react-navigator. However it did only did this error on one page. On said page I had a rogue {this.setState({foo:bar})}. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: Or when you call a function without any user's interaction (called every time when rendered) from render() and those function has setState(). Which create an infinity loop.

Comment: Downvoting because this is the exact message RN displays. Not a useful answer

Comment: @HungrySoul I have exactly the same issue how to overcome that ?

Comment: @SagarRS Please try to debug your render method and specifically search for props of the component (like onPress, onTextChange, etc) that you ain't misusing the function calling(i recommend using arrow functions). In order to debug, you can try commenting and uncommenting the rendering code.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using Expo, restart Expo (terminate and open again). I don't know but it worked for me.